# Sequelize + Squel.js: DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: column X of relation Y does not exist

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, squel.js

I am using `squel` to build a PostgresSQL query and `sequelize` to provide the database connection and execute the query.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const squel = require('squel').useFlavour('postgres')

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/config/config.json')[env];
let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

const payload = {
    myId: 'foobar',
    timestamp: Date.now()
}

// Build the SQL query
let q = squel.insert()
            .into('animals')
            .setFields(payload)
            .toString();
console.log(q)

// Execute the SQL query
sequelize
    .query(q, { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

However, running the above code give the error:

> DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: column "myid" of relation "animals" does not exist

The SQL statement generated is

```
INSERT INTO animals (myId, timestamp) VALUES ('foobar', 1578360166225)
```

It seems that adding quotes to change the column names like `myId` into `"myId"` will work. If this correct, why is Squel.js not formatting the SQL statement this way?

Comment: How come you are not just letting sequelize handle the sql statements?  Just out of curiosity, you don't want to define the models?

Comment: @GregBelyea I have already defined the models (4000+) but is currently trying to reduce the CPU/memory load, so I thought that sending the SQL statements without loading the sequelize models can help with this. What do you think?